# Unable to upload Arduino sketch to Arduino Uno using AVR ISP MKII and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: arduino, avr, isp

About a week ago, I tried to use my Arduino Uno to program a a stand-alone ATmega328P with [Optiboot](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot). Not only was I unsuccessful, but now I can't upload sketches to the original ATmega chip. The "L" stays lit even when I press the reset button.

So I ordered an AVR ISP MKII to either unbrick my Arduino Uno or bypass the bootloader and upload a sketch. I followed the tutorials to use the ISP in Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin), I have the programmer set to AVRISP MKII and I tried to "Upload sketch using programmer". This is the response:

```
avrdude: stk500v2_command(): command failed
avrdude: stk500v2_program_enable(): bad AVRISPmkII connection status: Unknown status 0x00
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.
```

Comment: I've never used Arduino IDE to upload via ISP, but did you check the (serial) port selection?

Comment: 'The "L" stays lit' Where do you see that "L"?

Comment: @jippie Maybe it is [this](http://www.atmel.no/webdoc/avrispmkii/avrispmkii.hardware_statusled.html)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the "L" LED on the Arduino Uno that is connected to pin 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Uno's AVR is the 28-pin DIP, the cheapest, quickest, most painless way to fix it is to replace the chip with another boot-loader installed one, available from lots of suppliers.

An FTDI cable (USB-A -> serial TTL) is so easy and convenient to use with your standalone, there's no need to risk your development board.